# How to move a square using jQuery? User inputs pixels

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, user-input

I wrote a code for moving a square in jQuery (ex. 50px). Now I need the user to input the pixels (in a text field) that will define how much will the square go up, down, left or right. Here is some of the code I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#down").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({
        marginTop:"100px"
    }, "slow");
});
```

I need the `marginTop` value to be flexible. Please help. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code can be written in a better way.. I will leave this to you :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#uparr").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      marginTop: (parseInt($("div").css("marginTop")) - parseInt($("#marginTop").val())) + 'px'
    }, "slow");
  });
  
  $("#downarr").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      marginTop: (parseInt($("div").css("marginTop")) + parseInt($("#marginTop").val())) + 'px'
    }, "slow");
  });
  
  $("#leftarr").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      marginLeft: (parseInt($("div").css("marginLeft")) - parseInt($("#marginTop").val())) + 'px'
    }, "slow");
  });
  
  $("#rightarr").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      marginLeft: (parseInt($("div").css("marginLeft")) + parseInt($("#marginTop").val())) + 'px'
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#down {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='marginTop' value='100' onchange='$("#down").click'/>
<button id='uparr'>Move up</button>
<button id='downarr'>Move down</button>
<button id='leftarr'>Move left</button>
<button id='rightarr'>Move right</button>
<div id='down'></div>
```